Пропал визуальный редактор в WP. Как его вернуть?
Пропал визуальный редактоор в WP. Не пойму почему. Буду рад любой помощи!


Отключай все плагины один за одним. Если это не поможет перейди на дефолтную тему, если это поможет, значит проблема в одном из подключений в functions.php. Если и это не поможет, откатывайся на старые бекапы, возможна проблема в коде базы данных.

Логи ошибок на сервере помогут разобраться.
Так же рекомендую поставить health check и посмотреть какие есть проблемы у сайта. При необходимости с ним можно отключить все плагины только для админа и таким образом найти виновного.

Плагин не выявил проблем. Заметил, что такая ситуация происходит только с кастомными записями

@Pavel ну очевидно, как-то неправильно их сделал.
